# On factoring $2+128(a+b)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Factor $2+128(a+b)^3$

$=2[1+64(a+b)^3]= 2[1+64(a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3)]$

Then I'm at a loss for what to do.

$=2[1+64(a^3+b^3)+192ab(a+b)]= 2[1+64(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)+192ab(a+b)]=2[1+64(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2+3ab)]=2[1+64(a+b)^3]$

Back to where I began...

But the answer is given as $2[1+4a+4b][1-4(a+b)+16(a+b)^2]$

I cannot comprehend how it's possible to factor into this answer. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Treat $a+b$ as a variable, call it $x$ and see that $2 + 128x^3 = 2(1 + (4x)^3)$

Comment: I see. But how do you know to treat a+b as a single entity in the first place? Is this intuition, just the method for this specific type of problem, or something else? Because I would assume most people would open up $(a+b)^3$ first, but clearly that's the wrong way here. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! It's kind of intuition, I don't expand first because there isn't any individual $a$ or $b$ present on the problem. That makes considering $a+b$ as one variable makes sense.

Comment: It is not intuition. You should be actively looking for such substitutions. In this case, note that $64=4^3$ so you have the term $4^3(a+b)^3=(4(a+b))^3$ as used in an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, in fact consider
$$2[1+64(a+b)^3] $$
and recall that  $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$. In your case, take $x=1$ and $y=4(a+b)$.
Hence you have:
$$2[1+64(a+b)^3]=2[1+4(a+b)][1-4(a+b)+16(a+b)^2]  $$